# SQL Join with Multiple Rows of a Single Table

Tags: sql, join, netezza

Disclaimer: I'm not sure how to title this question correctly, so I apologize if it has been asked already.  The questions I found with similar titles and content did not address my problem.

I have two tables, Issues and Text.  Issues and Text both share an ID column that acts as the primary key for Issues.  Text uses ID and Field as the key columns.

Ultimately I would like a sql query that selects the content in Issues I want, then based on the ID selects the correct values from Text.  I've been using joins, but I don't know to get it to work when I want multiple rows.  I'd like to have column A in the output for the matched ID's and a Text.Field value of A, and column B for matched ID's and a Text.Field value of B.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

**I'm pulling from a Netezza environment, so Pivot is not available**

Thanks

Example Structure:

```
Issues Table:
|ID|Column1|Column2|
--------------------
|0 |     17|     18|
|1 |     19|     20|

Text Table:
|ID|  Field| Value |
--------------------
|0 |      A|     30|
|0 |      B|     31|
|1 |      A|     40|
|2 |      B|     41|

Output:
|ID|Column1|Column2|Column3 (Field = 'A') | Column4 (Field = 'B')|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0|     17|     18|                   30 |                   31 |
| 1|     19|     20|                   40 |                   41 |
```

Comment: Is there a 1 to many relationship between the table Issues and Text?

Comment: You mean 1 row of Issues corresponds to multiple rows in Text? Yes.  Issues has ID as the primary key.  Text uses ID and Field.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is `pivot` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+sql

Comment: It would be helpful if you would list your table structure, at least with respect to their primary key, relevant foreign keys, and output columns you desire.

Comment: I'm pulling from a Netezza Environment, so Pivot is not available.

Comment: @NathanTornquist: `Pivot` is a generic technique, which has a dedicated command in SQLServer - see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[pivot]+[sql]+-sqlserver for other RDBMSs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Issues.ID, 
    Issues.Column1, 
    Issues.Column2, 
    Text.Value Column3,
    Text2.Value Column4
FROM 
    Issues LEFT OUTER JOIN Text ON Text.ID = Issues.ID AND Text.Field = 'A'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Text AS Text2 ON Text2.ID = Issues.ID AND Text2.Field = 'B'
```

Comment: I'm typing up a visual description of the table structure now, but if you see the second paragraph of the description you can see that that won't work.  Text requires two primary keys.  I'd like to have different columns in the output based on the value of the Field key.

Comment: I've posted the complete description above.  I just added the table example.

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen the other comments, Pivot is not available.  I'm using Netezza

Comment: I'm getting the error: This form of correlated query is not supported.  Do you have any other ideas on how to do it, or will I just have to compile the data outside of the SQL environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select i.id,
  i.column1,
  i.column2,
  max(case when t.field='A' then t.value end) Column3,
  max(case when t.field='B' then t.value end) Column4
from issues i
left join text t
  on i.id = t.id
group by i.id, i.column1, i.column2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98d34/1)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd say left joins are a little wasteful and not required, though occasionally required in other case (ugg)

Make sure Field/ID fields all have indexes, and this will be super fast

```
SELECT 
    Issues.ID, 
    Issues.Column1, 
    Issues.Column2, 
    TextA.Value as Column3,
    TextB.Value as Column4
FROM 
    Issues
    Text as TextA
    Text as TextB
WHERE
    TextA.ID = Issues.ID
    AND TextA.Field = 'A'
    AND TextB.ID = Issues.ID
    AND TextB.Field = 'B'
```